# How to get slide effect like iphone home screen

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview, core-animation, uigesturerecognizer

Can anybody tell  me how can i get exact smooth slide effect as of home screen of iphone ??? I have two `UIView` to slide left and right.

Comment: Add those views in UIScrollView and enable **paging**

Comment: And for those who have considered this question as off-topic, i would like to say that If you can think form questioners point of view, better to stay away. And very much thanks to suhit & surya for helping me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use UIScrollView and add all your views to the scrollview and enable paging. Alternatively you can use iCarousel and add all your views to carousel and select linear type, it has paging as a property which can help you to archive what you want. here are the links for

[scrollview paging](http://www.iosdevnotes.com/2011/03/uiscrollview-paging/)

and [iCarousel](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel)

Comment: I have used UIScrollView and enable paging on that. I was not aware about this concept. Thanks for help.

Comment: glad that you like the idea.

Answer (score 1):

make use of **UIPageViewController**  or (if you found that confusing and you're happy to use collection views) make a **full screen collection view** with cell size of your screen and use a simple pageControll down on screen ... and enable paging of collectionView